# Directional derivative and maximum of it

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am having the function $$ f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}$$
and I need to find the directional derivative at point $(1,-1,1)$ for every $\vec{v}$ $\in{\mathbb{R}^3}$
by using the **definition** of the partial derivative. and also I need to the determine what is the max and min that the $\partial f(1,-1,1)$ at any $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ can have.

So my problem is first to calculate the limit by definition, I am getting an expression like $$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{1+tv_1} + \frac{1}{tv_2-1} + \frac{1}{1+tv_3} -1}{t\sqrt{v_1^2 +v_2^2 + v_3^2}}$$

I have no idea how to go on from here, and also, how I should understand the second part of the question, about the minimum and maximum of the directional derivative at the point $(1,-1,1)$

thank you kindly.

Comment: What if you did $\nabla \vec f(1,-1,1) \cdot \vec v$

Comment: @Nεo Pλατo As it says in the question, “find the directional derivative ... by using the definition of the partial derivative.”

Comment: @amd I'm honestly just using scraps of knowledge from Khan Academy videos. As far as I know the gradient has the partial derivatives which when dotted with the vector gives the directional derivative. If you put up an answer I'll have a good look at it though

Comment: The algebra is a bit tedious, but not really that hard to grind out. The expression eventually simplifies and factors nicely.

Comment: @amd would you help me caculate the limit?

Comment: Turn the numerator into a single fraction in the same way that you would any other sum of fractions: find a common denominator and expand and simplify the resulting sum of products for the numerator.